# Post jQuery form serialized data to php

Tags: php, jquery, forms, post

I'm trying to post a serialized data from jQuery to php like the following.

```
$.post(location.href, $('form').serialize(), function(data){
    // do something
});
```

It's working very well. But is there a way I can set a name to the serialized data, so I can use that name for `isset()` function? It'll look like this:

Let's assume the form has

```
<input type="text" name="input1">
<input type="text" name="input2">
```

`file.js`

```
$.post(location.href, {data:$('form').serialize()}, function(data){
    // do something
});
```

`file.php`

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['data'])) {
        // retrieve the data in the serialized string and use it in a function
        helperFunction($_POST['input1'], $_POST['input2']);
    }
?>

<html>
    // rest of the layout
</html>
```

I don't want to use a button to submit the form. The reasons I don't want it are:

1. Using `<button type="submit">Submit</button>`, then submit the form to the same page will ask for re-submission when I refresh the page (which I don't want it) after I submit the form.
2. Using jQuery to post the serialized data to the server will not ask for re-submission when I refresh the page after I post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add a hidden variable and check it in post value.

```
<input type="hidden" name="check_val" value="chek_val" />
```

```
<?php
```

if(isset($_POST['check_val'])) {

}
?>

Comment: How does this actually work? That hidden input will be inside the serialized string as well. Or do you mean that hidden input will always be set; thus, the form is being posted to server?

Comment: I chose this answer because of its simplicity for debugging and modifying current code. And it works great!

Answer (score 1):

Since PHP parse arrays from submitted POST data you can manipulate like this:

```
<input type="text" name="inputs[data][1]">
<input type="text" name="inputs[data][2]">

<?php
    if( isset( $_POST[ 'inputs' ][ 'data' ] ) ) {
        helperFunction( $_POST[ 'inputs' ][ 'data' ][ '1' ], $_POST[ 'inputs' ][ 'data' ][ '2' ] );
    }
?>
```

But actually I don't see a reason why not to do more simple:

```
<input type="text" name="input1">
<input type="text" name="input2">

<?php
    if ( isset( $_POST[ 'input1' ] ) &&
         isset( $_POST[ 'input2' ] ) ){
        helperFunction( $_POST[ 'input1' ], $_POST[ 'ipnut2' ] );
    }
?>
```

Comment: I don't do that because my forms have a lot of inputs, selects, and/or, textareas. Do you have another way for lots of data?

Comment: @Lancelot Why don't you try the first way provided? Group data into arrays.

Comment: I prefer not to, because the first way will be hard to think (when debuggin/reading the code) which data I'm actually passing to the function. However, I do appreciate your suggestion as I didn't know I can put it as an array.